# Joining two tables with no common column

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to join two tables together combing two fields in table 1 to form composite keys and  combining two fields in table 2 to form composite keys.

The primary keys will be dropped because tables get truncated in ETL

```
CREATE TABLE collection]
(
    collectionid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    spaceid INT NOT NULL,
    collectionpa VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    collectionto VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE objects
(
    birstobj INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    birstspace INT NOT NULL,
    collectionid INT NOT NULL,
    object_nm VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    object_label VARCHAR (150)NOT NULL
)
```

composite keys in table 1 spaceid and collectionpa 
composite keys in table 2 birstspace and collectionid

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide an example?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: thank you @marc_s. I have updated the query

Comment: You can join on anything you like, doesnt have to be a column, it could be a substring, a constant, a concatenation, or any other expression. Just be aware that it might have to scan the table rather than follow foreign keys and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

A join condition is just like any other SQL condition - you can use both the columns there:

```
SELECT *
FROM   collection c
JOIN   object o ON c.collectionid = o.collectionid AND
                   c.spaceid = o.birstspace
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried the code and it worked, However I didnt see my data. it returned 0 rows.

Comment: @joela can you please edit your question and share some sample data? Perhaps I'm overlooking something here